# How to put an fix image background for ScrollView?

Tags: android, layout

I should want the scrollview scroll, but not the image in its background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background_image"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <ListView
  android:id="@+id/category_list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

 <TextView
  android:id="@android:id/empty"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the Linearlayout holds the backround image. The list will be displayed above this with an transparent background. For further informations on this topic have a look at [ListView Backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html)

Answer (score 6):

Add the image higher up the view hierarchy ahead of your scrollviews frame

Comment: I'm sorry : your answer help me too, but I've only one "accepted answer". Planty of thanks to you :-)